# Jenkins Pull Request Builder start build old closed pull requests

Tags: git, jenkins, pull-request, ghprb

I am trying to setup Jenkins to trigger build on opening and merging pull requests.

I created a pull request from branch A to B. Then closed it (PR-1). Build started and completed successfully.

Next, I created a pull request from same branch A to same branch B (PR-2). After success build Jenkins started build PR-1 again.

Same if I closed PR-2 and created PR-3. Jenkins will start builds for PR-1 and PR-2 again!

This is my setup for Jenkins job.

[image]

Why does Jenkins start to build old closed pull requests?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [JENKINS Multi-Branch Project Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Multi-Branch+Project+Plugin), now [JENKINS Pipeline Multibranch Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Multibranch+Plugin) should be the one allowing to build only branches with new commits.

If you don't use that plugin, the refspec `refs/remotes/origin/pr/*` would select all PR branches.